# Can a digital meter be damaged when reading resistance but connected to AC voltage

Tags: multimeter, damage

While testing with multimeter like a fluke 177 or fluke 334 clam meter in ohms range, if it is connect to ac voltage up to 50 volts, does it damage the multimeter?

Comment: No, the meters are protected.

Comment: Hmmm.  Nothing I can find (handbook or calibration) says how well the inputs are protected.

Comment: @JRE Fluke EU/US models with CAT rating are protected for the CAT specified voltage on all inputs. Though that protection may include the blowing of fuses and it may be "time limited" by the life span of MOVs and other such.

Comment: [Ah.  There it is.  Page 3, CATIII 600V.](http://assets.fluke.com/manuals/33x_____cieng0300.pdf)  [Measurement categories on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurement_category)

Answer (score 2):

Short answer, it's perfectly safe for you (*) and the meter. At least when using a quality meter such as Fluke. Fluke is protected up to 1000Vrms on non-current inputs. Obviously 1kV is not safe for YOU but the meter won't mind. Here's the [datasheet of the 170 series DMMS](http://assets.fluke.com/datasheets/2155a.pdf).

[Here's a youtube video](https://youtu.be/zUhnGp5vh60) that explains more about DMM protection than you possibly would want to know.

And here's [a link to the Fluke 27 service manual](http://www.testmart.com/webdata/mfr_pdfs/FLU/27______smeng0100.pdf) he uses as basis.

(*) *Perfectly* safe is probably going too far. According to IEC62368-1, 50VAC rms is safe for "instructed person" i.e. service guys. 30VAC rms is safe-safe. Still, 50VAC is unlikely to harm you in most cases. IEC TS 60479-1 classifies that as AC-2 and describes it thus: *"Perception and involuntary muscular contractions likely but usually no
harmful electrical physiological effects"*